# Ubuntu 12.04 in a 2 months old Toshiba Satellite

Tags: brightness

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a 2 months old Toshiba Satellite C75 AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics × 4 and 4gigs of ram.

It doesn't detect my laptop internal wireless card only my external Netgear USB wireless card.
Every time i turn on my computer the screen is dark. in order to make it bright i have to go to setting and adjust the brightness.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Windows 8.1  O.S

Answer (score 0):

Asking one question at a time will help us answer.

The first step to answering your question about your wireless card is to determine what kind it is.  Run the following command to identify your wireless card.

```
lspci -v
```

Then see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported
and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

If these do not help you, post the output of lspci -v here.